# Extending Tridion Experience Manager

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

We are looking for some examples / explanation on how to extend Experience Manager

We want to add a layer / popup window that shows webanalytics data of that page/component, similar to the (show property) layer / popup.

But right now, we have no clue on how to create these buttons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say "Similar to show Property", is extending the Properties Dialog an option, we do this for SmartTarget

```
            <ext:deckpages>
                <ext:add>
                    <ext:extension assignid="TargetedRegionsPropertyPanel" name="TargetedRegionsPropertyPanel">
                        <ext:control>~/Controls/PropertiesBox/PropertyPanels/TargetedRegionsPropertyPanel.ascx</ext:control>
                        <ext:pagetype>TargetedRegionsPropertyPanel</ext:pagetype>
                        <ext:apply>
                            <ext:view name="EditorView">
                                <ext:control id="PropertiesBox_deckControl" />
                            </ext:view>
                        </ext:apply>
                    </ext:extension>
                </ext:add>
            </ext:deckpages>
```

Answer (score 7):

The trick to extend the Experience Manager view is all hidden in the configuration of your editor (extension).

If you take a look at my [example UI extension](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/example_ui.aspx) on SDL Tridion World, you can see in the config file that there are two `ext:editorextension` elements configured, one with the target `CME` and the other using `SiteEdit`. The rest of the configuration is in my example almost identical (as this extension is done for both the CME and the Exprience Manager view), appart from the `ext:view` names (these can differ slightly between the CME and XPM).

So use the following as a basis for your editor configuration, and then you extend where wanted:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
               xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
               xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
               xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu"
               xmlns:edt="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge">
    <resources cache="true">
        <cfg:filters />
        <cfg:extensiongroups />
        <cfg:groups />
    </resources>
    <definitionfiles />
    <extensions>
        <ext:editorextensions>
            <ext:editorextension target="CME">
                <ext:editurls />
                <ext:listdefinitions />
                <ext:itemicons />
                <ext:taskbars />
                <ext:commands/>
                <ext:commandextensions />
                <ext:contextmenus />
                <ext:lists />
                <ext:deckpages />
                <ext:tabpages />
                <ext:toolbars />
                <ext:ribbontoolbars />
                <ext:extendedareas />
                <ext:optionspanels />
            </ext:editorextension>
            <ext:editorextension target="SiteEdit">
                <ext:editurls />
                <ext:listdefinitions />
                <ext:itemicons />
                <ext:taskbars />
                <ext:commands/>
                <ext:commandextensions />
                <ext:contextmenus />
                <ext:lists />
                <ext:tabpages />
                <ext:toolbars />
                <ext:ribbontoolbars />
                <ext:extendedareas />
                <ext:optionspanels />
            </ext:editorextension>
        </ext:editorextensions>
        <ext:dataextenders />
    </extensions>
    <commands/>
    <contextmenus />
    <localization/>
    <settings>
        <dependencies>
            <editor>CME</editor>
        </dependencies>
        <defaultpage />
        <editurls />
        <listdefinitions />
        <itemicons />
        <theme>
            <path>/Themes/</path>
        </theme>
        <resourceextensions />
        <customconfiguration />
    </settings>
</Configuration>
```